# Disable Outlook Security Notice

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/jihrg.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8B30.png)

How do I disable this popup from appearing in Outlook for users?

I have tried to add a few settings in group policy, but upon further inspection the policies I have enabled in "User Configuration/Policies/Administrative Templates/Microsoft Office/Security Settings/Trust Centre/Trusted Location #X" affect a whole slew of office products, *but not office*

I am running office 2016 on this domain, and would like to suppress this alert message entirely, as it is being triggered when the users email each other known good files from their share drives.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The hyperlink security warning could be disabled via the following registry key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Security

DWORD: DisableHyperlinkWarning

Value: 1